# Convertir la ultima palabra de una cadena en mayuscula

Tags: c++, string, bucle-for

Estoy intentando hacer que la ultima palabra de una cadena introducida se convierta a Mayuscula, el problema es que no se como detener el for cuando encuentre un espacio, lo intente poniendo que sea hasta que i!='\0' pero como i se declara como entero creo que no reconoce caracteres. Este es mi codigo. Un ejemplo seria: Maria va a la escuela y me devuelva: Maria va a la ESCUELA.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
void mayuscula(string cadena,int n)
{int i; char aux;
     for(i=n; i!='\0'; i--)
    {
        aux=toupper(cadena[i]);
        cadena[i]=aux;
    }
    cout<<cadena;
}
int main()
{int n; string cadena;
    cout<<"Introduzca una cadena:"; getline(cin,cadena);
    n=cadena.length();
    mayuscula(cadena,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por si a caso, `i` es la variable de iteración y es un número. Lo que te interesa comparar con `\0` es el caracter en la posición `i` (`cadena[i]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` es un índice, es decir, es un valor numérico que va de `0` a `n`.

El caracter `\0` se encuentra en `cadena` y es ahí donde tienes que ir a buscarlo:

```
for(int i=n; cadena[i] != '\0'; i--)
```

Pero esto no te va a funcionar por tres razones:

1. `\0` únicamente se encuentra al **final** de la cadena. Si iteras desde el final hasta el principio ... no vas a dar con un `\0`. En cambio sí que te vas a encontrar un **espacio** cuando sobrepases el inicio de la última palabra.
2. No puedes empezar a iterar en `n` sino que debes hacerlo en `n-1`. El motivo es que si una cadena tiene 5 caracteres, los mismos se encontrarán en el rango 0-4
3. Deberías plantearte el caso en el que la cadena está compuesta por únicamente una palabra.

Aplicando estos puntos, el bucle quedarías así:

```
for( int i=n-1; i >= 0 && cadena[i] != ' '; i--)
```

Aunque también podrías usar `n` directamente:

```
for (n--; n>=0 && cadena[n] != ' '; n--)
```

Por otro lado, date cuenta que no hace falta usar `aux`:

```
cadena[i] = toupper(cadena[i]);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, por aclararme todos los conceptos.